# HTTP persistent connection in C#

Tags: c#, http, persistent-connection

I have to make an HTTP persistent connection to a chinese security camera so I can obtain certain thermographic information. The manufacturer told me that they implemented HTTP persistent connection (I have never made persistent connections before).

This is the code I have right now:

```
        var uri = new Uri($"http://<cam's IPv4>/ISAPI/Thermal/channels/2/thermometry/realTimethermometry/rules?format=json");

        var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
        credentialCache.Add(uri, "Digest", new NetworkCredential("test", "test"));

        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
            Credentials = credentialCache
        })
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

The thing is I'm not getting any response at all. How can I transform this code to HTTP 1.1 or make a persistent connection with this?.

For what I have been reading, there should only be an initial request and then I would keep receiving responses. Or at least that is what tbe manufacturer is telling me:

> if you already called  GET
> /ISAPI/Thermal/channels/2/thermometry/realTimethermometry/rules?format=json
> and established a connection, just receive alarms from the connection,
> please do not call GET
> /ISAPI/Thermal/channels/2/thermometry/realTimethermometry/rules?format=json
> again

Comment: The more common way to describe this would be a “streaming” http server. Use `ReadAsStreamAsync` Instead of string. You will need to handle framing, though.

Comment: I guess, "persistent connection" in this context means that the server continuously writes to the response stream. So, as long as the connection is open, the response stream will be open. As a consequence, `return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` will never return as long as the connection is open. It may seem to you that you are "not getting any response at all", but this may not be true. Instead, the `await` takes forever to finish.

Comment: So... to be clear... this is not regular HTTP persistent connection right?. It is not HTTP/1.1 protocol request right?